# How to Add driver to modifier SimpleDeform-angle by scipt python in blender 2.8

Tags: python, add-on

I create script , that script add object, now i create, a modifier , and i want to simulate “Swinging” but i can not understand how it can be done,does anyone know how I can do? :

```
bend = object.modifiers.new(name="bend", type='SIMPLE_DEFORM')
bend.deform_method = 'BEND'
###noob example:
bend.angle.driver_add("sin(frame/20)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consult docs or other questions on how to add a driver**

Here is your "noob" code edited to add a driver. Select a mesh object and run script.

It so happens that the current `context.scene.frame_current` is known to the driver namespace as `frame` so no driver variable need be created.

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
bend = ob.modifiers.new(name="bend", type='SIMPLE_DEFORM')
bend.deform_method = 'BEND'

fcurve = bend.driver_add("angle")
driver = fcurve.driver
driver.expression = "sin(frame/20)"
```

Also remember that angles when scripting are natively in radians.  2 pi radians = 360 degrees.  So at frame 20 the angle of bend will be sine of 1 radian (or around 57 degrees.)  Use `sin(radians(frame) / 20)` if frame is expected as degrees.

Comment: scuse me batFinger, fcurve = bend.driver_add("angle"). and  for get("angle")? i try but give me error

Comment: `bend.angle` or `getattr(bend, "angle")`  From the driver try `fcurve.evaluate(frame)` but not sure if this will work as expected.

Comment: im not sure, i try to put getattr(bend, "angle") in a function with update, 1 function create modifier and driver, then , the funcion(update) make parameter, but not , work.I do not know if it is appropriate to open a new question

Comment: IMO It's appropriate.

Comment: 'float' object has no attribute 'driver'. error